# How to change an answer into a comment when Reviewing Low Quality Posts?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, comments, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

Too often when I Review "Low Quality Posts" I see an answer which should get changed into a comment.  Is this a feature request which is intentionally not implemented ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators can do this, so it is a possibility right now. However, we only do it in cases where the comment adds value to a question or answer. "Me too" or "I have a different question" style non-answers are not worth preserving, and tend to be the most common ones of these we encounter.

If this was exposed to the community at large through the review queues, I think there's a concern that many of these worthless comments would be preserved, cluttering up questions or answers.

Also, there's an interface issue in that you'd need to be able to specify what post to make this a comment on. It's not always the question, and there can be multiple answers where it might end up. I imagine that would be a trickier thing to add as a feature for the review interface.

If you see something that adds value and absolutely should be preserved as a comment, feel free to use a custom moderator flag and tell us this. We can convert from there.

Comment: Better yet, integrate the information into the question or answer you'd ask for the comment to be placed on, if possible.